# How Do I Automate Daily Emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking though the system and can't seem to find a way to schedule a daily email to at list. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to automate some mails to contacts or you do you have just list of email ids?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, we have a list of emails that have subscribed to this particular email.

Comment: subscribed to this particular email?? which email? How they have subscribed? If you want to schedule daily email to list of email addresses then you can use apex scheduler and write some apex to send emails.

Comment: Yes to this particular email, they have subscribed via a signup form on our website. I'll take a look at apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Marketing Cloud, you can create a [User-Initiated Send](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/) that combines the email and the audience.

Once that's done, you can create a [Program](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/programs/) in Interactions or an Automation in [Automation Studio](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/automation_studio/) to send that email on a schedule.

Comment: "Apex"? I'm taking it that these subscribers are being stored as Salesforce CRM Contacts or Leads? If so, ok1ha can add them to a Salesforce Campaign or include them in a Salesforce Report (include Lead or Contact ID in the fields of the report) and use this Report as the audience used in the User-Initiated Send.

Comment: User-initiated send and Program did the trick. Thanks so much!